# Why this program is generating wrong answer?

Tags: c, arrays, character

This program is not giving the correct output; and it is taking input once instead of 't' times, while entering for the first time in the for-loop.

This problem is HEADBOB (https://www.codechef.com/problems/HEADBOB)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    for(t; t>0; t--)
    {
        int J=0, Y=0, N=0, I=0, len=0;
        if(len==0)
        scanf("%d", &len);
        char ar[len];
        for(J=0; J<len; J++)
        {
            scanf("%c",&ar[J]);
            if(ar[J]=='Y')
                Y++;
            else if(ar[J]=='N')
                N++;
            else if(ar[J]=='I')
                I++;
        }
        if(I>0)
            printf("INDIAN\n");
        else
        {
            if((Y&&!N)||(N&&!Y))
                printf("NOT SURE\n");
            else if(Y&&N) printf("NOT INDIAN\n");
        }
    }
}
```

INPUT:

NUMBER OF TEST CASES

NUMBER OF CHARACTERS

N NUMBER OF CHARACTERS

SAMPLE INPUT & OUTPUT OF ABOVE CODE:

INPUT:

5

5

NNYNN

OUTPUT:

NOT INDIAN

Comment: `if(len==0)` is always true.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a debugging service.

Comment: all-capital names are often reserved for macros and constants. And using all caps means you're shouting at people

Answer (score 1):

Check, if `scanf("%c", &ar[j])` is reading whitespace characters! Think about

```
scanf(" %c", &ar[j]);
```

That means to skip all whitespace characters (space, tabs, `\n`s, etc).
Or even better:

```
scanf("%d", &len);
char ar[len + 1]; // + 1 for 0-termination
scanf(" %s", ar); // skip all whitespace characters, then read a string
```

Reading full string in one shot is a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the second `scanf` (`scanf("%d", &len);`) leaves a newline character in the standard input stream (`stdin`). This character is then consumed by the third `scanf` (`scanf("%c",&ar[J]);`) in the first iteration of the loop.

Changing

```
scanf("%d", &len);
```

to

```
scanf("%d%*c", &len);
```

will fix the problem. `%*c` tells `scanf` to read and discard a character.